# Make a model for grouping multiple value in java

Tags: java, grouping

This is surely obvious but I'm stuck on it.

I want to have something like that

```
group1 {
name="boo";
gender="male";
}
...
groupN {
name="baa";
gender="female";
}
```

all the group have the same member.
and when i make function

```
function(Group group) {
blabla = group.name;
bloblo = group.gender;
}
```

I know how to do it but it's not pretty at all , and I'm sure there is a way to do it cleanly

Comment: @eephyne, it looks more like Javascript than Java so it was a fair question.

Comment: i know it doesn't look like java , because i don't really know how to write it (for the first part)

Comment: @eephyne, many people interchange the two, and the code you posted looks a lot like JavaScript. That's why I asked. It's unclear to me what it is you're trying to do. Instead of (trying to) explain it with pseudo-like code (that looks like JavaScript), could you explain it in English instead?

Comment: @Bart Kiers,don't get it wrong , i didn't say it aggressively , sorry if you get it like that. (in fact i'm have some king of trouble with Shakespeare language)

Comment: @eephyne, although your reply was a bit short, I didn't think you were being aggressive. The fact remains that I'm still unsure what you're trying to do.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is some kind of catalog of 3d objects , each group concern one object , and contain the obj file link and texture image link .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is not designed to be pretty or a functional language.  It is fairly likely that the simplest way/most natural way to do what you want is to use a plain loop without a "function"

Perhaps if you can be more specific we can help you more specifically.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is some kind of catalog of 3d objects , each group concern one object , and contain the obj file link and texture image link (so far). I tried to use static class inside class but it doesn't fill my need

Comment: @eephyne, a static class can be used to do what you describe.  Tell me more about the need it doesn't fill.

Comment: well,i make a static final class object .Inside i put some static final class <name of the object> and inside them the member i need to declare (the two link). But i don't know how to write a type like <object.*> in a function declaration

Comment: If you have a class B inside A, you can refer to it as A.B just like any other member. Even A.B.C.D.E.F etc.

Comment: yeah but the function doesn't have to know if this A.group1 or A.group2 , it just need to know this is a group inside A and have member object_file and texture_file. This is what class is not what i'm looking for i think

Answer (score 1):

> all the group have the same member

You're describing classes. This is the exact Java equivalend of your code:

```
public class Group{
    public String name;
    public String gender;

    public Group(String name, String gender){
        this.name=name;
        this.gender=gender;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Group group1 = new Group("boo", "male");
        ...
        Group groupN = new Group("baa", "female");
    }

    public static void function(Group group){
        String blabla = group.name;
        String bloblo = group.gender;
    }
}
```

I suggest getting an introductory Java book and reading the chapters on OOP. The [Java tutorial chapter on OOP](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html) works as well.

Comment: yeah that's the way i used , but i'd like to make all static final and not need to declare them each time i start the program

Comment: @eephyne: no problem at all. You can have the declarations (like they appear in my main method) as static final fields of the class. You probably couldn't do it because you wanted to set properties directly. If you use a constructor as in my code, you can have the initialization together with the field declaration.